# Finding connected routers in same isp

Tags: networking, ip

Can I view how many routers are connected to the same internet service provider in which I am connected?

I am connected to the router and router is connected to internet service vendor in which many other routers are connected too.
 So I want to view how many routers are there and their mac address. Is it possible?. If possible how can i view it ?

Answer (score 0):

Router are IP level equipments.

In this generic scheme :

```
You(MACY)----IP/Ethernet--->Router1(MAC1)----IP/Ethernet--->Router2(MAC2)
```

You will only know the MAC of the first hop (MAC1 of Router1) because you speak Ethernet with it. Other Mac address are not exposed to you.

You can know the different hops that are between you and an other host using traceroute. It is going to report routers' IP addresses (if the router permit it).

```
traceroute en.wikipedia.org
```

But a router will never tell you what other routers are connected to it. This is part of the routing table which is private information.